# I do not see my location on the map

Tags: java, android, location, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I try search my location in the google maps api combination with google places api and I only see the places makers but I don't print my geolocation.

(sorry but my english.. I hope understand me...)

my code is in a fragment:

```
public class MapFragmentActivity extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
private static View gv;

GoogleMap googleMap;
List<Place> findPlaces;
GPSLocation gps;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if (gv != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) gv.getParent();
            if (parent != null){
                parent.removeView(gv);
            }

     }
     try {
         gv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.principalayoutmap,container, false);    

     } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
     }

    gv.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

    gps = new GPSLocation(gv.getContext());

     if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        new GetPlaces().execute();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
     CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude()),100);
     googleMap.moveCamera(update); 
    return gv;
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    //Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView");
    googleMap.clear();
    Fragment f = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}


class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //this.listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeName));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                findNearLocation();

            }
        });        

        return null;
    }

}

public void findNearLocation()   {

    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    PlacesService service = new PlacesService("****xvRF1RH4tMq1************");


    double lat = gps.getLatitude();
    double lon = gps.getLongitude();

        findPlaces = service.findPlaces(lat,lon,"food");

        for(int i=0;i<findPlaces.size();i++){

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
             .position(new LatLng(findPlaces.get(i).getLatitude(), findPlaces.get(i).getLongitude()))
             .title(findPlaces.get(i).getName())
             .snippet(findPlaces.get(i).getVicinity())
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));  
        }
    }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The GPSLocation.class is a class for search my location and help print the near places

the Manifest.xml:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zape.zapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<!-- Google Maps related permissions -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network connectivity permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Access Google based webservices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.loggin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.loggin.Registrar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.principal.PrincipalMainMap"></activity>

         <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AI***GwDUTs6hb6VE8eoG****"/>
        <activity android:name="com.principal.MainFragment"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My principalMapLayout.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I delete my API KEYS for security, this is not a problem.

finally, I show this in my deivce (NEXUS 4):

[image: asd]

as can seen only print the places mark but i dont print my geolocation

Comment: Is gps.canGetLocation() true?

Comment: yes, this class is for places marks.. if gps.canGetLocation() was false, not print places marks..

Comment: And Google's maps app displays your location? Maybe it's a problem with the device ...

Comment: is posible... before I came out fine, but when I tried to remove my location and start to leave my GPS Intent, when activated, does not return me to the application, but again inciarla has left me leaving my location, but if the Places Marks (i write in google translate, sorry)

Comment: you know a any option for remove the all application to avoid any remains of the former, for example in cache??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happens because when I run the app without GPS, I check this option and I execute a intent for activate the GPS, when I activate gps, I press the back button and the intent no return in my app... 
after i try again open my app and the app location me but not print my location but places marker location yes...

exemple: 
first time I open the application, the app run good:
[image]

Now, open the aplication without GPS and show this alert:

[image]

I open this intent and activate the GPS, after I try return the app but i don't return for the first moment, but after I open the app but I don't print my location:
(1. my problem is that I'm not back well from GPS settings)
(2. when I open now my app.. I don't find my location)

[image]

anyone knows why is this happening?
I use a Nexus 4(android 4.4 rooted, stock fw)..
**This problem is in other device too... I can try in other deviche(Galaxy s3) and I have same result**